# Why do we add speeds of trains/buses moving in opposite directions to compute their relative speed in the context of calculating their meeting point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I just want to understand the logic behind adding or subtracting individual speeds in questions with similar context.

For example: P & Q are 300 km apart. At 8:00 am, buses X and Y left P & Q simultaneously for Q & P respectively. If the speeds of buses X and Y are 40 kmph and 60 kmph respectively, when do they meet?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is not linear-algebra

Comment: Please help me figure out a suitable tag; am a novice.

Comment: "Why do we add speeds ?" Just look at an example : Suppose , you are driving in a car and move $20m$ per second in some direction. Another car moves also $20m$ in the opposite direction. Suppose, you start at the mark $0m$ and the other car at the mark $100m$. After one second, you reach mark $20$ and the other mark $80$ , the distance is now $60$ , it decreased by $40$, the sum of $20$ and $20$. Hope that helps.

Comment: Every hour bus X covers $40$ km, and bus $Y$ covers $60$ km of the road, so they together cover $100$ km. The moment they meet is the moment they together covered the entire road, i.e.$300$ km. This takes $300/100=3$ hours. (Perhaps you can also imagine that those are not buses but those road line painting vehicles, in which case "covered" would literally mean "covered by paint".) ;)

Comment: Thank you @Peter and @StinkingBishop!!! The painting-idea is good! Helps in visualisation!

Comment: The correct word for "speed" here is actually velocity. Now, since velocity is a vector, in order to compute the relative speed, these vectors in opposite directions must be added. Now if it were force instead of velocity we'd do the opposite.